# Почему у меня не перелезают данные из DataTable в DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

```
    DataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from " + SelectObject.Text + ";", MyLib.MyConnection); //Создаём адаптер-посредник
    CommandBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(DataAdapter); // Для адаптера доступно UPDATE
    dTable = new DataTable();
    this.dGrid1.DataSource = dTable;
    MyLib.MySQLOpen();
    dTable.Clear();
    DataAdapter.Fill(dTable); // Всасываем данные из адаптера в dTable
    int NRows = dTable.Rows.Count, NColumns = dTable.Columns.Count; // Как в БД
    int NRows2 = dGrid1.Rows.Count, NColumns2 = dGrid1.Columns.Count; // <b>Нули!!!</b>
    dGrid1.DataSource = dTable; // Связываем данные с демонстрируемым элементом dGrid1 формы 
    MyLib.MySQLClose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте. Возможно, этот полный пример поможет Вам разобраться с Вашим вопросом. Мне кажется в простом, но полном примере проще разобраться, чем в отрывке кода. Есть Excel файл, который заполнен данными. Программа считывает эти данные и заполняет многострочное текстовое поле и DataGridView.

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

//подключить пространство имен
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace _0003 {
 public partial class Form1 : Form {
  string connectionString = null;
  OleDbConnection connection;
  string sql = null;

  public Form1() {
   InitializeComponent();
   textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "*.xlsx;*.xls";
   openFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel 2007 и выше(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|Excel 2003(*.xls)|*.xls";
   openFileDialog1.Title = "Выберите документ для загрузки данных";
   openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
   if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    textBox1.ReadOnly = false;
    textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;

    connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + openFileDialog1.FileName + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR = YES"";";
    using(connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)) {
     try {
      connection.Open();

      //получаем список листов в Excel файле
      DataTable schemaTable = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });

      //выбираем название первого листа
      string sheet1 = (string)schemaTable.Rows[0].ItemArray[2];

      sql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", sheet1);

      //заполняем многострочное поле
      OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);
      OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      while(reader.Read()) {
       textBox2.Text += " " + reader[0] + " " + reader[1] + " " + Math.Round(decimal.Parse(reader[2].ToString()), 2).ToString() + " " + "\r\n";
      }

      //заполняем таблицу
      //при помощи класса OleDbDataAdapter и его метода Fill данные загружаются в Dataset
      System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter ad = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      ad.Fill(ds);

      //создаем таблицу, которая будет источником данных для таблицы dataGridView
      DataTable tb = ds.Tables[0];
      dataGridView1.DataSource = tb;
     }
     catch(Exception exc) {
      MessageBox.Show("Ошибка соединения!\n" + exc);
     }
     finally {
      connection.Close();
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Когда я пересоздал Windows Form приложение "с нуля", отказавшись от всяких примочек/мастеров Studio для связи с БД, всё заработало. На это решение меня натолкнуло то, что ранее подобный код нормально работал в случае с БД SQLite без этих примочек. Всё же спасибо за подсказку.